# Angular 2 - Sort list from Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs5

What is the best way to `sort` a list of items coming from an `Observable` and still be able to use the `async pipe`? (I read that making a custom sort pipe is not really efficient.) I want to avoid subscribing and keeping a local copy of data and thus just using async pipe...

```
//can I use map here and filter items right in the observable and get rid of subscribe?

this.test$ = Observable.of(['one', 'two', 'three'])
    .subscribe((data) => {
        data.sort((a, b) => {
            return a < b ? -1 : 1;
         });
        this.data = data;
     });
```

template:

```
<div *ngFor='let item of data'>
<!-- want to be able to use async pipe here -->
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you call `.subscribe()` you get a `Subscription`, the async pipe expects an `Observable`.

If you change it to

```
this.test$ = Observable.of(['one', 'two', 'three'])
.map((data) => {
    data.sort((a, b) => {
        return a < b ? -1 : 1;
     });
    return data;
 });
```

you can use the async pipe with `test$`

Comment: Thanks Günter for confirming that I can use the Observable's map operator to sort, appreciate it.